# DOM Elements loaded from ajax and (probably) not ready in time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, jquery-isotope

I'm using sorting/filtering jQuery plugin [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) and also jQuery $.ajax() to dynamically load some new elements to the page that need to be sorted with Isotope. That library seems to set all the new sorted elements with absolute position and with fixed (left, top) position in order to perform sorting.

The problem is that when you load the **first set** of elements with **clear cache** the the element positions in that absolute grid are incorrect (they are overlapping). This is caused by Isotope initialization. My (inexperienced) guess would be that the all the new DOM elements are not fully loaded by the time Isotope starts to calculate the future positions of the elements and there's where the in-accuracy comes in. If I do the exact same ajax request again it manages to calculate the positions correctly.

**EDIT #1 ajax reuqest**

```
var $isocont = $('#page-content-result');
var isoActive = false;

$.ajax({
   url: actionUrl + 'ajax',
   type: 'POST',
   data: searchData,
   success:function (data) {              
       if(data.trim().length > 0) {             
            $('#page-content-result').hide().empty().html(data).fadeIn(600);   
            initIsotope();          
        } else {                                      
            var visible = $('#page-content-result').is(':visible');
            if(visible === true) 
            {
                $('#page-content-result').empty();                                
            }
            $('#result-notif').show();
        }
    }
});

var initIsotope = function() { 
    if(isoActive === true) {
        $isocont.isotope('destroy');
        console.log('iso stop');
        isoActive = false;
    }
    if(isoActive === false) {
        $isocont.isotope({
            getSortData: {                
                name: '.iso-docname',
            }
        });  
        console.log('iso start');
        isoActive = true;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain the nature of this problem and give few hints for solution? 
Thnx!

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some code, perhaps the .ajax callback for the data? success: or .done?

Comment: Sure, here you go. :)

Comment: Hmmmm...Looking at the Isotope website, I wonder if a simple initialization before the data is requested by ajax might be helpful. Also I wonder if putting all of the isotope calls into a .done (or success in your case) statement would allow the data to be fully called first, then placed and manipulated by isotope. I'll continue reading...

Comment: Tried doing simple init. after page was loaded it doesn't seem to have changed anything. Also I tried adding 2 line after data was pushed into DOM with .html(). I though that it would be good idea to 
    `$isocont.isotype('reloadItems'); //to load new elements

    $isocont.isotype() //to re-arrange new elements, otherwise left:0, top:0 for all elements`

but that test ended with the same results - overlapping elements.

Comment: I could try to replace the isotope with some other alternative library since I'm not married to it yet. Seems that there's quite a lot of hassle over simple things. 
I just though that I made some kind simple and obvious n00b mistake but seems that it's more complicated.

Comment: I'll give [MixItUp2](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) a try for a sec. I'm starting to believe that Isotope isn't just worth of out time.

Comment: Any way that you might do a preliminary in just pure js? Sort the elements in an array, then distribute?

Comment: Well I was especially looking for that nice and interactive sorting and filtering. The most working way I've found by now is to not to init. isotope until the sorting button is clicked. Then the elements are drawn correctly to the DOM and finished up and later the isotope is inited and sorted. The only problem with that is that it's changing the visual side a bit by setting **position: absolute** and **adding 15px** to the left. If I could find out how to disable that left: 15px then I would be happy camper. 
Btw. Tried the MixItUp for second , that just doesn't cut the mustard.

Comment: Some of the options look interesting like isOriginLeft. I'm wondering if you can override the style with a js to all elements after the isotope finishes.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow morning, I'm in GMT+2 .

Answer (score 0):

Seems that once again the "morning is smarter than the night" (it's a saying in Estonian :P). 
I placed a piece of test-code after part where the new data was inserted to the DOM.

```
if (/complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
    alert('loaded');
}
```

The alert kind of pauses the loading of the page and I realized that the containers where quite a lot shorter because of the not-yet-loaded images. Meaning the DOM doesn't have the information how high the containers are going to be when we initialize the Isotope and that's why the Isotope fails to calculate the correct positions.

**FIX:** After understanding the problem the fix is really simple just tell the DOM how high the image is going to be in CSS with `min-height: 122px;` and that is all. I guess if the image height varies then I believe setting an interval checker for `document.readyState == 'loaded'` would help. 
Idea came from that blog http://callmenick.com/2014/06/04/check-everything-loaded-javascript/

So my general js file now looks something like that:

```
var $isocont;

$(document)(function() {
    //When DOM create a var of selector.
    $isocont = $('#page-content-result');
    //One time aka first init of Isotope with basic options.
    $isocont.isotope({
        getSortData: {                
            name: '.iso-docname',
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
       url: actionUrl,
       type: 'POST',
       data: searchData,
       success:function (data) {              
           if(data.trim().length > 0) {             
                //Set HTML data from ajax request
                $('#page-content-result').hide().empty().html(data).fadeIn(600);   
                //Reload isotope items and re-arrange the items according to config. 
                reloadIsotope();          
            } else {                                      
                //DO SMTH
            }
        }
    });
});

var reloadIsotope = function() { 
    $isocont.isotope('reloadItems');
    //We are resetting sorting since we might not want same ordering as on last result.
    $isocont.isotope({sortBy: null, sortAscending: true});  
}
```

Thanx TimSPQR for looking into!